# Is there a penalty for switching gear mid-combat?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I swap gear mid-combat (perhaps with a hot-key) to switch from heavy DPS to increase % chance of obtaining a blue item, is there any penalty for doing this?

Will I receive a less a % chance if I switch mid-combat than I would if I switch prior to engaging in combat?  (Such as: Is there a small cool-down prior to actually obtaining that item's bonus?)

Comment: It's... really inconvenient and difficult to do reliably?

Comment: Is it not possible to map a hot-key change?

Comment: no, it's not possible to hotkey equipment changes.

Comment: Blizzard doesn't even let you rebind the left-click button. You think they're gonna let you hotkey something in your inventory? :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diablo 3 has no concept of "In Combat". (This is the main reason your "Massacre" bonus can end while you're still fighting tooth and nail)

Everything is calculated when it happens. If you've got the horsepower to swap gear between each kill, all the more power to you, but it's a lot of work for a lot of very minor gain.

Unlike switching skills, there appears to be no penalty to switching equipment.

In the discussion leading to patch 1.0.4, Blizzard asked for solutions to Magic Find gear swapping.  Some of their own suggestions included penalties for said gear swapping.  **In the end, they did not change the way gear swapping works.**  They simply added a 300% MF/GF cap.