# Is MF gear swapping still working?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a penalty for switching gear mid-combat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66745/is-there-a-penalty-for-switching-gear-mid-combat)

I wonder is MF gear swapping still working immediately or have a cooldown after 1.0.4 patch?

I didn't found any topic about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It still works exactly the same as before 1.0.4, but magic find is capped to 300% so it will become increasingly pointless as you get closer to reaching the highest paragon-level.